# Program described Print file line cropping issue

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

I have 2 copies of the same program, in different libraries.  The programs are identical.
When I run it in the one library my spoolfile gets created to 192 positions per line.  But in the other library it adds a linefeed at 132.
The print is created in the program with:
FQSYSP75   O    F  196        PRINTER OFLIND(*INOF)

I am stumped.  As it uses the same QSYSP75 out of QUSRSYS for both libraries.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!  It turns out that there is an application that overrides the print settings.  Sorry to waste everyone's time!